# Shell Script for search and copy

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I'm new to Shell scripting and this is what I am looking for-

I need to unzip the .gz tar files in a directory into a temp sub-directory inside this directory.
I need to search for a string pattern in the files of this temp directory. After the search, I have to copy the the file names and the corresponding lines in which this String occurs to a new file. And finally I have to delete the temp directory

Any help is welcome. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
grep -r 'foo' /bar > baz.txt
```

- search recursively in `/bar`
- search for string `foo`
- output file names and matched lines
- send output to `baz.txt`

Edit for
[icktoofay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200291)
who did not read the man

```
SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]

OPTIONS
       -R, -r, --recursive
              Read all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively;  this  is
              equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

Comment: grep <pattern> <filename> >> newfile 
Worked out fine

Answer (score 0):

if you found it using grep , then just redirect it to some file.
and this is what is needed for you:

```
grep 'string' *.* > output.txt
```